# How do I slice a row and the preceding row based on two column values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I’ve taken the difference between the values in the month column to create the difference column.

```
data_2019['difference'] = data_2019.groupby('propertyId')['month'].diff()
```

[image: current state]

Now I’d like to do the following:

For every row that has a 1 in the difference column, keep that row and the row preceding so long as the propertyId value is the same as the preceding row.

[image: desired state]

Comment: Can you post code to create your dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can accomplish this:

```
# True for the second row of two consecutive rows
data_2019['difference+'] = data_2019.groupby('propertyId')['month'].diff()==1

 # True for the first row of two consecutive rows
data_2019['differenc-'] = data_2019.groupby('propertyId')['month'].diff(periods=-1)==-1

# 'keep' is True if a row is the first or the second or both
data_2019['keep'] = data_2019['difference+'] | data_2019['difference-']


Out:

    propertyId  month   occ     difference+ difference- keep
0   a111        3       80.0    False       False       False
1   a111        5       93.0    False       True        True
2   a111        6       94.0    True        True        True
3   a111        7       95.5    True        False       True
4   a111        10      88.0    False       False       False
5   b111        2       97.0    False       True        True
6   b111        3       99.0    True        False       True
7   c116        2       97.0    False       False       False
```

Then you can keep rows where `data_2019['keep']==True`

```
data_2019 = data_2019[data_2019['keep']==True]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following. If it doesn't work please let me know

```
df['new_diff'] = df['difference'].shift(-1)
df['new_propertyid'] = df['propertyid'].shift(-1)

mask = ( df['difference']==1) | ((df['new_diff']==1) & df['new_propertyid']==df['propertyid'])

ans = df[mask]
```